# Java Scanner input mishap

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So i have this program that takes in an input from the user and checks if it is suitable to become their password. To be suitable the input must be at least 8 characters long, contain only digits and letters, and contain at least 2 digits. I also had to encorporate some exception handling so if the input was not suitable to be a password, the program would display the appropriate errormessage and return to the input prompting stage. But if the password is valid the program needs to give a prompt to the user asking fi they would like to close or rerun the whole program over.

What I have done is create a do while loop inside of a bigger while loop, the program runs perfectly for catching the invalid inputs and displaying the appropriate errormessage but i realize when the repeat entire program prompt comes up and the user presses 1 to rerun the program, the prompt for the user password input reads in that 1 and displays it as an invalid password. I need to figure out how to make sure my password prompt doe snot read in the rerun program input. My code is as follows:

```
       import java.util.Scanner;
       public class Ed10Chp6Ex6Point18CheckPasswordProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program will...");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int repeatInt = 1;
    boolean Continue = true;

    while(repeatInt == 1){
        do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a password that....");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        if(checkPassword(password) == "Congradulations, the password you have entered is valid!"){
            System.out.println(checkPassword(password));
            Continue = false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(checkPassword(password));
            Continue = true;
        }

        } while (Continue);

    System.out.println("To repeat the program enter 1 for yes or 0 for no");
    repeatInt = input.nextInt();
    }   
    }

//check password method
public static String checkPassword(String x) {

        String errorMessage = "Congradulations, the password you have entered is valid!";

        //must have at least eight characters
        if (x.length() < 8){
            errorMessage = "The password you entered is invalid, password must be at least 8 characters";
            return errorMessage;
            }

        //consists of only letters and digits
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i))) {
                errorMessage = "The password you entered is invalid, password must contain only letters and digits";
                  return errorMessage;
              }
            }

            //must contain at least two digits
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
              if (Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i))){
                count++;
              }
            }

            if (count >= 2){
              return errorMessage;
            }
            else {
                errorMessage = "The password you entered is invalid, password must contain at least two digits";
              return errorMessage;
            }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use the `equals()` method to compare `String`s.

Comment: Also try adding a `input.nextLine()` after `input.nextInt()` to consume the whole line.

Comment: ILikeTau Thank you!!!! That worked perfectly